# Undefined index al intentar hacer uso de una variable en php

Tags: php, html

En la página de lista que es la consulta de la base de datos, llamo en los registros a `empleadoID` para poder usarlo en otro pagina que es para modificar los datos de la base de datos, pero me sale como que nunca lo hubiera definido.

----------Aquí es la página donde lo declaro, en los últimos 2 `echo`------------

```
 <?php
  include("basededatos.php");
  $conexionbd=conectar_bd();
  $query ="SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado;"; 
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
  mysqli_close($conexionbd);
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
            <h1>Lista de empleados</h1>
            <ul>
                <?php
                   while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
                   {
                    echo '<li>'.$registro['nombre'].' ('.$registro['edad'].'años)';
                    echo '<a href="modificarEmpleado.php?empleadoID ='.$registro['id'].'"> Modificar</a></li>';
                    echo '<a href="eliminarEmpleado.php?empleadoID ='.$registro['id'].'"> Eliminar</a></li>';
                   }
                ?>
            </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Aquí es donde lo quiero usar en `$query`, pero me dice que no está definido, pero ya yo lo defino en la otra:

```
<?php
include("basededatos.php");
$conexionbd = conectar_bd();
$query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado Where id".$_GET['empleadoID']."LIMIT 1";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
mysqli_close($conexionbd);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modificar Empleado</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="actualizarempleado.php" method="post" name="nuevoempleado">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="empleado_nombre" value="<?php echo $registro['nombre']?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    Edad: <input type="text" name="empleado_edad" value="<?php echo $registro['edad']?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="empleado_id" value="<?php echo $registro['id']?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="actualizar empleado">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Aquí los errores:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: empleadoID in C:\xampp\htdocs\modificarempleado.php on line 5

 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\modificarempleado.php on line 8
```

Comment: no eso brother, ya lo he intentado

Comment: aun lo tienes??

Comment: todavia me sigue con el error. es en esa declaracion que no me la quiere aceptar no entiendo porque

Comment: de dado caso que no entiendas, te invito a ver mi ejercio a ver si puedes ver algo que no estoy viendo y me ayuda. mi curso lo estoy haciendo en https://aprende.org el curso es **desarrollador de Back-end** en el nivel 2, leccion 4

Answer (score 3):

Deberías hacer los siguientes cambios:

- En el bucle `while` donde se pintan todos los registros y generas el enlace para mostrar los registros con base en el `id` que mandas por la URL.

Código

```
echo '<a href="modificarEmpleado.php?empleadoID='.$registro['id'].'"> Modificar</a></li>';
echo '<a href="eliminarEmpleado.php?empleadoID='.$registro['id'].'"> Eliminar</a></li>';
```

> Es decir quitas el espacio en blanco que este entre el símbolo de igual y la variable que envias

- Segundo en la página donde recibes dicha variable, no la pases directo a la consulta; antes asignala a una variable y usa esa en tu query, de este modo, *(no olvides que te hace falta el símbolo de igual)*:

Código

```
$id = $_GET['empleadoID'];

$query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad 
          FROM empleado 
          Where id = $id LIMIT 1";
```

- Ahora yo movería el cierre de la sesión, una vez hecho lo anterior ya pudieras estar visualizando los datos que resultaron de tu consulta filtrando por medio del `id`

Código

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE id = $id");

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $fila["nombreColumna1"];
    echo $fila["nombreColumna2"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prueba de esta forma:
<?php
  include("basedatos.php");
  $conexionbd=conectar_bd();
  $query ="SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado;"; 
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
  mysqli_close($conexionbd);
?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
            <h1>Lista de empleados</h1>
            <ul>
                <?php
                  
                    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                ?>
                 <?php 
                     echo '<li>'.$registro['nombre'].'('.$registro['edad'].'años)';
                     echo '<a href="modificarEmpleado.php?empleadoID ='.$registro['id'].'"> Modificar</a></li>';
                     echo '<a href="eliminarEmpleado.php?empleadoID ='.$registro['id'].'"> Eliminar</a></li>';
                 ?>
        
               <?php 
                  }
               ?>
            </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -1):

¡Hola!
¿No te faltaría el signo `=` en la siguiente línea?

Original:

```
$query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado Where id".$_GET['empleadoID']."LIMIT 1";
```

Modificado:

```
$query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad FROM empleado Where id = ".$_GET['empleadoID']."LIMIT 1";
```

Cuéntanos cómo te va. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias pero mi codigo todavia no entra...Tratare de reiniciar todo y crear otra base de datos, gracias por compartir tu tiempo para ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error similar al que preguntaste la primera vez?